# redirection to an action with asp.net mvc application using javascript call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have an asp.net application in which i have to custmize the action click in submit button of a form :

the Script

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    function result(arr, identificateur,Pages) {
   var f1 = $('input[name="reception' + arr + '"]').val();
   var f2 = $('input[name="client' + arr + '"]').val();
   var f3 = $('input[name="cloture' + arr + '"]').val();
   var f4 = $('input[name="tag' + arr + '"]').val();
   location = "@Url.Content("/Pages/Index")?identificateur=" + identificateur + "&Pages=" + Pages + "&_reception=" + f1 + "&_cloture=" + f3 + "&_client=" + f2 + "&_tag=" + f4;
    }});
  </script>
```

then, the form:

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="result(@i.ToString(),@Model[1][i].Id ,"1");" value="Enregistrer"/>
```

When i click into the submit button, nothing is happend and i'm not redirected to the action `Index`.

What are the reasons of this problem? How can i fix it?

**Edit**

```
<input type="submit" id="Enregistrer" value="Enregistrer" data-arr="@i.ToString()" data-identificateur="@Model[1][i].Id"  />





<script>
    $(function () {
            $('#Enregistrer').click(function () {
            var self = $(this); // This is the submit button
            var identificateur = self.data('identificateur');
            var arr = self.data('arr');
            var f1 = $('input[name="reception' + arr + '"]').val();
            var f2 = $('input[name="client' + arr + '"]').val();
            var f3 = $('input[name="cloture' + arr + '"]').val();
            var f4 = $('input[name="tag' + arr + '"]').val();
             document.location.href = "@Url.Content("/Pages/Index")?identificateur=" + identificateur + "&Pages=1&_reception=" + f1 + "&_cloture=" + f3 + "&_client=" + f2 + "&_tag=" + f4;
        });
    });
  </script>
```

The problems :

1. the redirection didn't work
2. Only in the first `tr` i can reach the `js` function

Comment: have you tried location.href = ... ?
or location.replace(...)

Comment: Please add your browser rendered html and javascript

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Does your code even reach the `result()` function? Try adding `console.log("IM IN RESULT()");` in the `result()` and check if it show in console.

Comment: i add an `alert("here")` in the beginning of `result` but no alert is appear!!

Comment: @Lamloumi, What was an equivalant js/html code rendered for your razor syntax. Please check the viewsource or response with firebug if it is a Ajax response. Like to see wat was actually rendered

Comment: try
window.location = controller/action/

Comment: You can't use many elements with the same id. Use the class instead. The class selector is `$(".className")` instead of `$("#id")`.

Comment: @KamilT : thanks i changed it but for the problem od redirection it still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I spotted two errors:

```
location
```

should be

```
location.href
```

And the second, try to prefix the function with `javascript:`:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:result(@i.ToString(),@Model[1][i].Id ,"1");" value="Enregistrer"/>
```

---

Or even better, use unobtrusive javascript with html5 `data-` attributes.

```
<input type="submit" id="Enregistrer" value="Enregistrer" data-reception="@i.ToString()" />
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
$('#Enregistrer').click(function () {
    var self = $(this); // This is the submit button
    var reception = self.data('reception');   // Get the data from the attributes.
});
```

Comment: @Lamloumi good point, I updated by answer. By the way, does the `javascript:` prefix work in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @Lamloumi is this submit button inside a `for(each)` loop, ie. is it on the page multiple times?

Comment: yes sorry @Henk i change the code : i proceed by class because i'm in a `for` loop. only the problem of redirection stays

Comment: @Lamloumi is the generated url correct? Try to use `@Url.Action("Index", "Pages", new { identificateur = identificateur, pages = 1, _reception = f1 })` with all the other parameters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38782/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-henk-mollema)

Comment: how can i put a javascript variables inside the `@Url.Action`

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `string parameter` with quote `'` like `'someVal'`, else you will get `undefined error`

Changing this below line

```
 onclick="result(@i.ToString(),@Model[1][i].Id ,"1");"
```

to

```
onclick="result('@i.ToString()','@Model[1][i].Id' ,"1");"
```

will make a call to your javascript function, otherwise all rendered string will be considered as variable like below and you will get `someval,someId undefined error`

```
onclick="result(someval,someId ,"1");"
```

Also use `location.href` for navigation

Comment: the problem is that i can't reach the javascript function not inside it

Comment: @Lamloumi, Updated the answer. Now you could able to reach your js function

Comment: the same result , i can't reach the js function

Answer (score 1):

Put the definition of `result()` function inside `$(function(){ /* put it here */  });` instead of simple `<script>`.

Also remember to put apostrophes instead of quotation marks in `onclick="result(@i.ToString(),@Model[1][i].Id ,"1");"`

when you pass the `"`"`.

**It should be**

```
onclick="result(@i.ToString(),@Model[1][i].Id ,'1');"
```

Comment: for the apostrophes i didn't understand you sorry